# sin cos arccos arcsin функции в Java

Tags: java

как реализовать функции sin cos arccos arcsin в Java?

Comment: Входной параметр угол. За основу берется единичная окружность

Comment: Math.sin(),  Math.acos() и так далее

Comment: Я знаю эти функции. Но я хочу реализовать свои и понять, как это рассчитывается в  коде

Comment: Посмотрите ряды Тейлора, многочлены Чебышева, алгоритмы CORDIC

Comment: Думаю это Вам поможет в поисках истины :))
https://habr.com/en/post/526000/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормальный в общем то вопрос, не знаю почему так активно минусуют. Как то уже отвечал на подобный вопрос, не поленюсь повторить:

1. Матфункции в Java реализуются не на чистой Java, а вызовом нативных
   (сишных) функций. Достаточно посмотреть на исходники Java, там все
   четко видно: [пруфлинк](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/StrictMath.java.html)
2. В нативной части, реализация `sin/cos` зависит
   от платформы. Для процессоров семейства x86 реализуется на
   ассемблере вызовом функции `fsin/fcos`, встроенных в процессор с
   плавающей точкой.
3. Для прочих процессоров Sun применяет (вернее
   теперь уже Oracle) широко известную в узких кругах вычислителей
   библиотеку [FDLIBM](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/)
4. Собственно сам [исходник синуса](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c) показывает, что там какие-то степенные полиномы (скорее всего Чебышев, а не Тейлор, поскольку Тейлор подходит только для аппроксимации в окрестности конкретной точки, а Чебышев/Якоби используются для аппроксимации в области):

```
 * kernel sin function on [-pi/4, pi/4], pi/4 ~ 0.7854
 * Input x is assumed to be bounded by ~pi/4 in magnitude.
 * Input y is the tail of x.
 * Input iy indicates whether y is 0. (if iy=0, y assume to be 0). 
 *
 * Algorithm
 *  1. Since sin(-x) = -sin(x), we need only to consider positive x. 
 *  2. if x < 2^-27 (hx<0x3e400000 0), return x with inexact if x!=0.
 *  3. sin(x) is approximated by a polynomial of degree 13 on
 *     [0,pi/4]
 *                   3            13
 *      sin(x) ~ x + S1*x + ... + S6*x
 *     where
 *  
 *  |sin(x)         2     4     6     8     10     12  |     -58
 *  |----- - (1+S1*x +S2*x +S3*x +S4*x +S5*x  +S6*x   )| <= 2
 *  |  x                               | 
 * 
 *  4. sin(x+y) = sin(x) + sin'(x')*y
 *          ~ sin(x) + (1-x*x/2)*y
 *     For better accuracy, let 
 *           3      2      2      2      2
 *      r = x *(S2+x *(S3+x *(S4+x *(S5+x *S6))))
 *     then                   3    2
 *      sin(x) = x + (S1*x + (x *(r-y/2)+y))
 */
```